# Embed Python3 + Dependencies into C++ Binary

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cython, embedded-linux

I have an application running on linux 2.6, which actually controls a robot. I have written a c++ infrastructure and API to allow a user to write a "Mainloop" in c++ for the robot. The function signature is RobotRunLoop(const Robot &robot). The Robot class provides all the APIs needed. The current system when compiled, sets up the enviornment and then calls the RobotRunLoop. I would like to be able to write the "mainloop" in python instead of c++. So basically the c++ startup, calls into the python mainloop, which will then use the provided api to call back into c++ to control the robot.

I assume I can make a similar RobotRunLoop in python with a similar robot object which contains the hooks to the c++ apis. I would like to be able to compile this into a binary which i can then run on the robot identically to the pure c++ version.

The motivation for this is to be able to experiment with machine learning models and approachs more easily in an experimental fashion. Getting something running with TensorFlow or similar package on the c++ infra would be the end goal

Is this even possible? What if the python code uses other packages? do i use cython or pybind11 (neither seem to do what I want)?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, see the Python documentation about [extending and embedding](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html). But the more "standard" approach would to [extend Python, not embed it](https://twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/rant/extendit.html).

You would create a Python module (compile a shared object with a python-specific C API) that wraps your Robot class. I would consider using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) or [swig](http://swig.org/) to help with that. You can run your C++ initialization code either when the module is loaded or (better) when an instance of the class is created.

Comment: so in this case if my main c++ program wanted to fork the python code off into its own process, then it could simply invoke the system command "python myWrapper"?